# Add special characters to alphanumeric regex

Tags: c#, .net, regex

Brand new to using Regular Expressions. I have one that currently accepts alphanumeric characters only. I need to add the following special characters to the regex:

```
@ #$%*():;"',/? !+=-_
```

Here is the regular expression:

```
RegularExpression(@"^[a-zA-Z\s.,0-9-]{1,30}$",
```

When I try to add the special characters, I alter the Regex like so:

```
RegularExpression(@"^[a-zA-Z\s.,0-9-@ #$%*():;"',/? !+=-_]{1,30}$"
```

However this throws an error starting with the `'` character that says `Newline in constant`.

I've tied to escape both the `"` and the `'` characters, however without any luck.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the problem comes from the double quote that need to be escaped (`""`), not from the single quote.

```
@"^[a-zA-Z\s.,0-9@#$%*():;""'/?!+=_-]{1,30}$"
```

note that the `-` must be at the last (or first) position in a character class, since it has a special meaning (define ranges)

Comment: `-` doesn't have to be at the begining or end to be parsed as literal. It can be between clauses or escaped.

Comment: Sorry, I thought this was for PCRE engine. I haven't tested it for C#, which may or may not be different.

Comment: This worked fine for me, and I'm using it in an ASP MVC website coded in C#. Thanks!

Comment: @sin: what are "clauses"?

Comment: @NealR - Not saying anything wrong with this char class. I was wondering about the location of `-` in the class. Try with my regex `@"^[a-z-A-Z0-9_\s.,@#$%*():;""',/?!+=]{1,30}$"`  or `@"^[\w-\s.,@#$%*():;""',/?!+=]{1,30}$"` it should work the same.

Comment: @Casimir et Hippolyte - I consider clauses isolated sub-structures in the class as parsing progresses left to right. For example [`\w`-`a-z`-`\pL`-`\s`] are clauses, everything else is a literal. In this case `-` is literal. C# parses classes differently, it has some special meta chars (like &&), so it may consider it differently.

Comment: On Perl/PCRE engines, `[a-z-A-Z0-9_]` and `[a-zA-Z0-9_-]` and `[\w-]` are functionally identical.

Comment: @sln: thanks for the information. Note that pcre has always the same behaviour: "when it is not ambiguous, you can do it".

Comment: Just confirmed, C# is the same `[a-z-A-z]` includes a literal `-`. Its really no suprise, there is no reason to unconditionally disallow it. In fact it would just get in the way.

Comment: @Casimir et Hippolyte - ok great!

Answer (score 0):

These regexs' are equivalent to yours.
Both use tilde `~` as the delimeter.
Both use double quotes on the regex strings.

Note that in order for the the dash `-` in class to be interpreted literally and not as a range operator, it must exist somewhere disambiguous, or be escaped.
A good place to put it is between valid ranges (or at the beginning or end of a class).
For example [a-z`-`0-9] is a good place.
*Edit - `'-'` Literal may have to be escaped or beginning/end of class. (This case was for Perl/PCRE engines)*

This one `^[a-z-A-Z0-9_\s.,@#$%*():;"',/?!+=]{1,30}$` is your regex without duplicate chars.

To make it more readable noting that the word class is contained, it can be reduced to
`^[\w-\s.,@#$%*():;"',/?!+=]{1,30}$`

*Edit - Php test cases removed.*

Comment: Sorry, I see this is C#. I could have sworn it was php.